# Enabling Spark logs in IntelliJ

Tags: apache-spark, logging, intellij-idea, log4j

I am running my spark jobs on intelliJ, and am getting the following error:-

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sanchay/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Log4j-slf4j/Log4j-slf4j-2.x.698.1338/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sanchay/brazil-pkg-cache/packages/Slf4j_log4j/Slf4j_log4j-1.7.2463.17539/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sanchay/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.16/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

However, when I run the same jar/class using the spark-submit, I am able to obtain all the INFO logs required :-

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/11/08 00:17:27 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
17/11/08 00:17:27 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/11/08 00:17:28 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: JavaSparkPi
17/11/08 00:17:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: sanchay
17/11/08 00:17:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: sanchay
17/11/08 00:17:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/11/08 00:17:28 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/11/08 00:17:28 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication dis
```

How can I switch to the default logging file in IntelliJ, so that I can obtain information regarding the Spark Ui etc via the INFO logs ?

Answer (score 0):

- assume that you manage code with maven. build dependency:tree and check what version of log libraries are used. https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html wil very good chart with infromation what libraries should be. All others should be excluded
- how do you build jar to be submitted to spark? I assume that you did not include all dependencies and as result you didn't have extra logging libraries.